# Wrong color for UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a background ImageView. Here is the view hierarchy. The imageView I'm talking about is highlighted in orange.

[image]

My problem is that the image is perfect in storyboard (strictly equal to original) but is a **little whiter in simulator and on real iPhone** when I run the app.

So far :

- I checked all tint colors and alphas in the view hierarchy.
- I used this code too :

  ```
  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cell Background")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
      print(backgroundImageView.highlighted)
  }
  ```

For now I cannot seem to find why there is this little (but design killing) difference between original image and rendered image.

Comment: is it cover full cell ? have u check bounds ?

Comment: @PKT The UIImageView doesn't cover full cell. The background color of the cell contentView is ok. The problem occurs only the UIImageView.

Comment: have you checked to see if the imageview is opaque? If its alpha isn't set to 1, then its color is probably being affected by whatever's behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem ! The issue was with the slicing of the images actually.

Automatic slicing went a bit too far and so the images didn't not take the center color into account but the shadow at both ends